# Prevent child element from moving outside parent when browser is resized?

Tags: html, css, position, media-queries

I've got a button with a logo on it. It looks like this normally:

`[ Logo         Centered Text              ]`

The button's got `text-align: center`, and the logo is relatively positioned to be placed at the left side of the button at all times. However, when the button's size decreases due to a change in the size of the browser, the logo, due to its positioning, sneaks out the left side of the button:

`Lo[go    Centered Text   ]`

How can make the logo stay put at the left side of the button, regardless of the button's size?

```
.button {
  text-align: center
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  right: 125px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/83vfft19/

Comment: That is because of the `right` property you have. Better if you could create a similar demo here. Along your HTML/CSS.

Comment: Did you try absolute positioning instead?

Comment: Can you post a Snippet or Fiddle showing what this should look like? I can think of a few different solutions but some of them may not be suitable to your requirements.

Comment: Hi all -- Thanks! I've updated the original post with with a link to a JSFiddle. Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/83vfft19/ @Shaggy

Answer (score 1):

If you set your parent .button position to relative, you should be able to absolutely position the child .logo within the parent.

Comment: Hey -- Thanks! We're getting closer. It looks like this would work in most cases. For my case, however, the logo is snapping back to a position near the center of the button at some smaller sizes. Any insight?